# LinkedHashSet or ArrayList

Tags: java, data-structures

I wish to

1. Avoid duplicated item being inserted.
2. When I iterate through the collection class, the returned item is same as insertion order.

May I know, what thing I should consider, to choose either ArrayList (explicitly perform contains check before insertion) or LinkedHashSet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Definitely use LinkedHashSet. It is made for what you need. Searching entire ArrayList every time you need to insert something will be performance killer (O(n) every time))

Comment: Of course the performance will depend upon sizes, frequency of operations, memory usage, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Use `LinkedHashSet` if you don't want duplicate items inserted.

Comment: And it also preserves insertion order http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 3):

Please check this out:
http://wiki3.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/images/e/e9/JavaCollections.png

LinkedHashSet is what you need, because it's an implementation of the **Set** interface. Set has one very cool habit: it doesn't allows duplicates by default. So, we are done with your 1.

What about 2?
We know, that we need one of the Set implementation, but which ?

**HashMap** - you are able to store K,V pairs, but there is no order.

**TreeSet** - this is the slowest solution, because it's using a `compareTo` method to keep every item sorted and ordered. This is why you can pass a comparator to it, when you are constructing a TreeSet.

**LinkedHashSet** - Gives back the elements in order of INSERTING them. It is the ordered version of a HashSet.

Please find a cool description here:
http://java67.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/when-to-use-linkedhashset-vs-treeset-vs-hashset-java.html?_sm_au_=iVVMtMLHSDQ5P0P7

Answer (score 2):

A `LinkedHashSet` seems to fit the bill perfectly.

When you build your own objects, and plan to use them in a Collection like `LinkedHashSet` here. Don't forget to override both `equals` and `hashcode` for the item you are going to store in it.